# where the behavior of private and static method is different from only private method

Tags: java, static, private, access-specifier

As for my understanding:

When a method is static it is

1. early bind
2. can call with the name of class even before no object is created
3. can call only static member inside it.

I never found any other behaviour of static either at compile time or runtime. **Is there any?**

When a method is private it is

1. also early bind
2. can only call inside call so can call directly without object.

For example the `hugeCapacity()` method in the `ArrayList` class.

```
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

private static int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    return (minCapacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) ?
        Integer.MAX_VALUE :
        MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
}
```

Since there are in Java private+static method exist. Why their need occurs. Is it for restriction purpose, to restrict access of non static variables inside a method?

Comment: The point is that static methods are associated with the type rather than with any instance of the type, whereas instance methods are associated with an instance of the type. The private part is entirely orthogonal to that. (For example, you can call a private static method without any instances ever existing...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually sir as for as private method is concern-they can call only inside a class.when You can call them as directly by its name, so why bound them with overhead of ClassName.methodName.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcortians: You don't have to specify `ClassName` to call a static method, if you're calling it within the same class (or a subclass). The point is that you should make a method static if it doesn't logically operate on an instance of the class - it's as simple as that.

Comment: exactly sir.I also have same point since a method which is private have same behaviour as prvate+static.each and every property of static method lost its existence in case of private method. Why private+static method's need occurs. Is it for restriction purpose, to restrict access of non static variables inside a method?

Comment: one more thing hopefully you answered in hurry.this static private method is not accessible in subclass :) @JonSkeet as u told-if you're calling it within the same class (or a subclass).

Comment: @dubey-theHarcortians: I was talking about static methods in general. Again, you're trying to tie two entirely orthogonal concepts together, and it's not at all clear to me why you'd wnat to do so. A private instance method does *not* behave the same as a private static method. Hint: try to access instance variables from a private static method... And if you're now going to say there's no point in private static methods: try calling a private *instance* method when you don't have an instance to call it on...

Comment: thanku sir.i found following summery-1-you can call this(private+static) method in another static method of same class even before no object is created.2- u can not access, non static instance member of class in it.

Comment: Yes. And that's *exactly* the same as for non-private static methods. As I say, they're orthogonal concepts. The *only* area in which they overlap is that non-private instance methods can be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you don't want to *expose* a method to the outer world and use it only *internally*, you can mark them as *private*. That applies to `static` methods as well. An example :

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeTestClass.display1(); // compilation error
        SomeTestClass.display2();
    }

}

class SomeTestClass {
    private static void display1() {
        System.out.println("displaying 1..");
    }

    public static void display2() {
        display1();
        System.out.println("displaying 2..");
    }
}
```

In the above code, `method1()` is supposed to be used only in class `SomeTestClass`. This increases *abstraction*.

Comment: "Well, if you don't want to expose a method to the outer world and use it only internally, you can mark them as static." No, you mark it as private...

Comment: @JonSkeet - I meant to say *private*, not *static*.  (A typing blunder nonetheless :P) Corrected it..